# disable android back button for modal <ion-modal-view>

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view, ionic-popup

I have the following modal inside an ion view:

```
<ion-view id="doctors" cache-view="false" view-title="Directorio médico"  ng-controller="DoctorsDirController as doctorsCtrl">
  <ion-content>
              <!-- stuff inside here -->
  </ion-content>  
    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            When this modal is open disable android back button
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~-->
    <script id="result-details.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-modal-view id="result-details-modal">
        <ion-content>

        </ion-content>
      </ion-modal-view>
    </script>
</ion-view>
```

This is the state for parent view (doctors) inside `config` in app.js:

```
 .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {

      .state('doctors', {
        url: '/doctors',
        templateUrl: "templates/doctors.html"
  })
```

So inside app.js `run`I tried:

1. disabling android back button for parent view
2. but for all other views act as normal back button.

Code:

```
.run(function ($ionicPlatform, $state) {$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {


    $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function () {
      //if we are in doctors do nothing
      if ($state.current.url == "/doctors") {
        //do nothing

        //else if we are in dashboard exit app
      } else if ($state.current.name == "dashboard") {
        ionic.Platform.exitApp();

        //else normal back-button functionality
      } else {
        navigator.app.backHistory();
      }
    }, 100);

  })
```

The problem is that when modal is called inside "doctors" it seems to be a different state from the parent "doctors" and my android back button overriding doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this to disable android back button in the modal:

`$scope.modal.hardwareBackButtonClose = false;`